# Polymer 1.0 very weird styling issue in paper-input

Tags: polymer

I have a page with this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/polymer/polymer.html'/>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html'>
    <link rel='import' href='bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html'>
</head>
<body>
    <dom-module id='base-page'>
        <template>
            <div style='width:400px'>
                <paper-input label='A' value='A'></paper-input> 
                <paper-input label='B' value='B'></paper-input> 
                <paper-input label='C' value='C'></paper-input>
                <paper-input label='D' value='D'></paper-input> 
                <paper-input label='E' value='E'></paper-input>
            </div>
        </template>
    </dom-module>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'base-page'
        });
    </script>
    <base-page></base-page>
</body>
```

The strange thing here is that the fourth paper-input is styled differently as it does not have the initial line under the area where data is to be entered. Why could that be?

Cheers

Comment: Works for me: http://i.imgur.com/4hi9Lzt.png

Comment: Could you please make a demo of that?

Comment: Argh ... yes, there is no problem except somewhere on my computer!! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my end and the example works fine